# Why do I get empty string when I use getString function?

Tags: android

When I run the app for the first time, the value of dateFormat is empty,
I'm very surprised, the dateFormat should return default vale"HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"

```
SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String dateFormat=dateFormat("SetDate", "HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"); 




<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:key="AppPreference"
    android:summary="@string/Preferencesummary"
    android:title="@string/Preference" >

     <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="\n"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/DateFormat"
        android:entries="@array/Mydate"
        android:entryValues="@array/Mydate_values"
        android:key="SetDate"
        android:summary="@string/DateFormatsummary"
        android:title="@string/DateFormat"
        android:layout="@layout/mypreference_layout" 
        />   

</PreferenceScreen>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string-array name="Mydate">
        <item>HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy</item>
        <item>HH:mm MM-dd-yyyy</item>
        <item>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="Mydate_values">
        <item>HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy</item>
        <item>HH:mm MM-dd-yyyy</item>
        <item>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: You need to add more context.  Maybe you can include you entire Java file (we need to know where you are calling SharedPrefs, etc - do you have context, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this looks like the problem to me:

```
android:defaultValue="\n"
```

Why would you expect a default value of `"HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy"` when you're explicitly setting it to `"\n"`? I suggest you change the default value, and see if that works...

(I'm not an Android developer, so maybe I'm missing something... but that seems like the obvious approach to me.)